# Magento 2 - How to add a new sort options in category page

Tags: magento2, php, category, javascript

I want to add a new sort options in the toolbar sorter. I want to add "**price low to high**" and "**price high to low**" in **Sort By** dropdown in product listing page.

I try to create a new module, I found this code but is not work:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_custom_block_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="custom_catalog_model_config" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
    </type>

</config>
```

---

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
    ) {

        $options['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
        $options['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
        return $options;

    }

}
```

---

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php
```

---

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{

    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
    ) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
    }

    return $result;
    }

}
```

Maybe someone has fix this already and will be nice if he will share the solution with us.

Thank you

Comment: Your code is working i check in default luma theme.

Comment: can't work because there exist that Ascending / Descending arrow too

Comment: so what you want to do in arrow i mean you easily disable  using css or else you write plugin in toolbar for public function afterGetCurrentDirection($subject, $dir)
    { .... } method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert You need to create another plugin for this method afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray  for Magento\Catalog\Model\Config example code is

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="catalogCompanyToolbar" type="Company\Sorting\Model\Catalog\Config"/>
</type>

protected function addNewOptions($arr)
    {
        // Here you write your custom method for sorting
        //$methods = $this->_helper->getMethods();
        foreach ($methods as $className => $method) {
            if (!isset($arr[$method['code']])) {
                $arr[$method['code']] = $this->_objectFactory->create(
                    ['data' => [
                        'attribute_code' => $method['code'],
                        'frontend_label' => $method['name']
                    ]]
                );
            }
        }

        return $arr;
    }

public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray($subject, $result)
    {
        $options = array();
        if (!$this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'company/general/hide_best_value',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
        ) {
            $options['position'] = __('Position');
        }
        foreach ($subject->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            $options[$attribute['attribute_code']] = $attribute['frontend_label'];
        }
        return $this->addNewOptions($options);
    }
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand very well? will not work to implement in this actual module ?

Comment: @Robert its work in your actual module this function use for keep magento default sort by in product list page. please check default function in magento  Magento\Catalog\Model\Config function public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()

Comment: I am lost, can you add the code or solution for this and tell me the path file where I need to add your code? Thanks

Comment: Check my update answer.

Comment: thanks in what file I need to add the code?

Comment: so what will do this code? because I need to remove the position attribute, there in the sorter will have only Product name, and price lo-hi and price hi-lo

Comment: <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="catalogCompanyToolbar" type="Company\Sorting\Model\Catalog\Config"/>
</type>

Comment: so I need to replace this file: app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php ?? with your code? please guide me step by step

Comment: or I need to create a new module?

Comment: you create this functionality for same module.

Comment: I see so I need to replace that Config.php code with your code?

Answer (score 1):

@Robert Yes it's working as per your query about Ascending/Descending arrow you manage using this plugin here is i write sample code for plugin you adjust logic as per your requirement

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
 * @param string                                             $dir
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function afterGetCurrentDirection($subject, $dir)
{
    $selectedDirection = strtolower($this->_toolbarModel->getDirection());
    if (!$selectedDirection
        && $this->reverse($subject->getCurrentOrder())
    ) {
        $subject->setDefaultDirection('desc');
        $dir = 'desc';
    }
    return $dir;
}
```

i hope you fix your issue.

Comment: Hi thank you, I have only one issue, if I disable any attribute from: Catalog > Categories > Display Settings > Available Product Listing Sort By the module is not work anymore. If I check Use All then the extension will work again. you have any idea?